# Octave says variables are undefined even when they are

Tags: octave

I have the following code

```
function W = robust(a,c,y)
  W = pinv(a' * c * a) * a' * c *y;
endfunction
```

However, when I try running it, I get the following error.

```
error: 'a' undefined near line 4 column 12
error: called from
    robust at line 4 column 5
```

This makes no sense at all.  What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: I'm calling this via emacs.  So, I'm using the command 'octave-source-file', which executes the file in the inferior octave process.   I see that it works if this buffer isn't where I start the process.  If I start the octave process on a different file and then send this file to the inferior process, it evaluates the function.

Comment: First define `a`, `c`, and `y` and then call that function. You cannot run a function as it is.

Comment: But I should be able to load this, right?  Works for another function that is something like

    function y = sigmoid(z)
      y = (1 ./ (1 + e.^(-z)));
    endfunction

Comment: How are you "running" the function? Your function *must* be called with inputs, not with F5.

Comment: I'm loading it via octave-cli (done via emacs).  Basically, it is the same as defining the function in the cli.

Comment: So...are you calling it with inputs or not?

Comment: Nope.  I'm defining it.

Comment: Call it with inputs

Comment: This is a typical case of a question which is missing the most important part: "Which action lead to the error". You've opened emacs, create a new file foo.m (add the real filename to your question) and then? I hope you are calling your function, like Sardar said, with inputs

Comment: Yep.  Added in the edit on what I did.  Got confused with the behavior when I called another function file with the same structure but was a different file.  Kind of counter-intuitive given that the function keyword ought to dis-disambiguate a declaration and a call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Octave has inherited from MATLAB a concept of "function files", different from "script files". A "function file" is assumed to contain a function that needs to be **called** as the file is executed. So when you think "I'm defining it", Octave thinks you are calling that function. And since you gave no inputs, there is that "undefined variable" error.

[Function files](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Function-Files.html#Function-Files):

> Once Octave finds a file with a name that matches, the contents of the file are read. If it defines a single function, it is compiled and executed.

[Script files](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Script-Files.html#Script-Files):

> Unlike a function file, a script file must not begin with the keyword function. If it does, Octave will assume that it is a function file, and that it defines a single function that should be evaluated as soon as it is defined.